# react and redux error on production env

Tags: reactjs, redux, production

I receive this errors from react and redux when I tried to deploy my test app. But these errors don't appear on my local machine.

But then I realized that my local machine is not using the minified version of the bundle (but my deployed app is using the minified version), so I minified the bundle, then boom! the errors appeared. Any idea why this happens and how it can be fixed?

Thanks in advance for those who would help.

[image]

Comment: which bundler are you using? Any chance you could share your build process, cause without it, this question is pretty much useless

Comment: The errors already contain pretty much everything, including links to explanations and tutorials. What more do you need?

Comment: fixed! thanks to @Sulthan for pointing out the links, I felt quite stupid for not clicking those links and not taking the time to read those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I get it.

So when minified, react is looking for the `process.env.NODE_ENV` and checking whether it is set to `production`. there are two solutions for this:

**Solution one**

The easiest way of doing this (if you're using webpack, which is, I am) is to run `webpack --define process.env.NODE_ENV='\"production\"'` which will take care of it for you.

**Solution two**

is to add these on your plugins in your `webpack.config.js` file.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
    }
})
```